# Sorting one array by sorting two other arrays together

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, sorting

I apologise for the title of this question that I know is very unclear, I tried my best.

I have three arrays that need to be sorted, but the tricky rule is the following:

- the first array needs to increment every time, and when the maximum is obtained, goes back to zero.
- the second array has to be sorted starting from the minimum to the maximum.
- The third array is the most complicated one: each position MUST correspond to the doublet of numbers that are in the two firsts arrays. For example, if before sorting, the letter `'L'` in `array3` was at the same position as the doublet `(0, 1)` in the two firsts arrays before sorting, it should be the same after sorting.

Because the explanation may be not very clear, here is an example of the starting point:

```
import numpy as np

array1 = np.array([ 0 ,  0 ,  1 ,  1 ,  2 ])
array2 = np.array([ 1 ,  0 ,  1 ,  0 ,  0 ])
array3 = np.array(['L', 'H', 'O', 'E', 'L'])
```

This is the desired output:

```
array1 = np.array([ 0 ,  1 ,  2 ,  0 ,  1 ])
array2 = np.array([ 0 ,  0 ,  0 ,  1 ,  1 ])
array3 = np.array(['H', 'E', 'L', 'L', 'O'])
```

This looks like a very simple problem, but at the moment I don't have found a solution to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a fourth array which is `array2 * (array1.max()+1) + array1`.  Then argsort that as the indices for array3.

```
import numpy as np
array1 = np.array([ 0 ,  0 ,  1 ,  1 ,  2 ])
array2 = np.array([ 1 ,  0 ,  1 ,  0 ,  0 ])
array3 = np.array(['L', 'H', 'O', 'E', 'L'])

to_sort = ( array1.max() + 1 ) * array2 + array1

array3[ np.argsort( to_sort ) ]
# array(['H', 'E', 'L', 'L', 'O'], dtype='<U1')
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a non-numpy solution. But

The desired order can be obtained by doing

```py
sorted(zip(array2, array1))
```

To obtain the list of indices (to reorder the word) you could do

```
indices, sorted_arrays = zip(*sorted(enumerate(zip(array2, array1)), key=itemgetter(1)))
```

indices is then

```
(1, 3, 4, 0, 2)
```

to get the output

```
"".join(array3[x] for x in indices)
```